# Trying to write to a CSV file but getting error message: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable

Tags: python, csv, file, file-io

I am trying to create a ticketing system using Python that is able to write and read to files, but the program doesn't seem to write anything. I'm getting the error message:

```
'_csv.writer' object is not iterable
```

"OKU" means disabled BTW.
"IC-number" is a Malaysian ID Number.

Expected Output:

```
Name    Age  Sex    Malaysian   OKU  IC-Number  Passport-Number  Fee
Jack    25   Male   0           0      -        12345678         23.70
```

I've attached the code below:

```
import csv

with open(input("\nInput file name with .csv extension: "), 'w+') as f:

    people = int(input("\nHow many tickets: "))
    name_l = []
    age_l = []
    sex_l = []
    local_l = []
    oku_l = []
    ic_number_l = []
    passport_number_l = []
    fee_l = []
    # visitors = 0
    adult = 0
    senior = 0
    child = 0       
    seniormsian = 0
    admsian = 0
    childmsian = 0
    foreigner_l = []
    adforeigner = 0
    childforeigner = 0      

    for p in range(people):

        name = str(input("\nName: "))
        name_l.append(name)

        malaysian = int(input("Malaysian (1 = Yes, 0 = No): "))

        age = int(input("Age: "))
        age_l.append(str(age))

        if malaysian == 1:
            oku = int(input("OKU (1 = Yes, 0 = No): "))
            oku_l.append(str(oku))
            if age >= 13 and age <= 59:
                fee = 17.80
                if oku == 1:
                    fee += 5
                print(fee)
                fee_l.append(fee)
                

            elif age >= 4 and age <= 12 or age >= 60:
                fee = 7.10
                if oku == 1:
                    fee += 5
                print(fee)
                fee_l.append(fee)

            else:
                fee = 0.00
                if oku == 1:
                    fee += 5
                print(fee)
                fee_l.append(fee)

            ic_number = str(input("Input IC Number: "))
            ic_number_l.append(ic_number)

            while len(ic_number) != 12:
                print("IC Number must be 12 digits long. Try again!")
                ic_number = str(input("Input IC Number: "))
                ic_number_l.append(ic_number)

                if len(ic_number) == 12:
                    break
            local_l.append(str(malaysian))

        else:
            if age >= 13:
                fee = 23.70
                print(fee)
                fee_l.append(fee)

            elif age >= 4 and age <= 12:
                fee = 17.80
                print(fee)
                fee_l.append(fee)
            else:
                fee = 0.00
                print(fee)
                fee_l.append(fee)

            passport_number = str(input("Input Passport Number: "))
            passport_number_l.append(passport_number)

            while len(passport_number) != 8:
                print("Passport Number must be 8 digits long. Try again!")
                passport_number = str(input("Input Passport Number: "))
                passport_number_l.append(passport_number)

                if len(passport_number) == 8:
                    break
            foreigner_l.append(malaysian)

        sex = str(input("Gender: "))
        sex_l.append(sex)

    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
    writer.writerow([name, age, sex, malaysian, oku_l, ic_number_l, passport_number_l, fee])
    for row in writer:
        writer.writerow([name, age, sex, malaysian, oku_l, ic_number_l, passport_number_l, fee])
```

Comment: not sure about last 2 lines of code. Why iterating on writer?
I guess what you wanted to do was iterate on each ticket `for i in range(people): writer.writerow([name_l[i], age_l[i]...)` but you could also move the definition of the writer object (`writer = csv.writer`) before the for loop and then indent one more time `writer.writerow([name, age, sex..])` so that it will be done on each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: I tried it just now but i still get the same error message. '_csv.writer' object is not iterable

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please include the entire traceback in your question.